# Itemize environment of longtables?

Tags: longtable, itemize

I want to make a list of longtables. The example shows that the table is not indented and the bullet point is not next to the table. How can I do this? It works if I use a tabular environment but I need longtable because in my document the tables are sometimes quite long and should be automatically splitted at page breaks.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
  \item \begin{longtable}[l]{ccc}
          ABC & ABC & ABC
        \end{longtable}
        \blindtext
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: longtables are always full width of the page (which is why they can page break) You can put bullets or item numbers in the first column of the table.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}[l]{l @{\hspace{1em}}ccc}
  \textbullet&       ABC & ABC & ABC\\
       &  ABCD & ABC & ABC\\
      &   ABC & ABCD & ABCD\\
 \end{longtable}
\begin{itemize}
\item[]      
\blindtext
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```